# Oauth redirection URL for google play auth

Tags: reactjs

I'm testing the Oauth connection in my local host. I need to specific redirection URL so I gave the following URL there.

```
http://localhost:3001/succesful/
```

On successful authentication, it gets redirected and appends with code and scope like this.

```
http://localhost:3001/succesful/?code=asasasa&scope=asasas
```

But for some reason, my URL is not loading. I have added route like this.

```
   <ProtectedRoute path="/succesful/:code?" component={Connection}/>
```

I'm new to programming, not able to understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `<ProtectedRoute path="/succesful" component={Connection}/>` This will work fine.

Comment: It's not working. Am I doing something else wrong

Comment: Is the url loading before the redirect happens ?

Comment: `ProtectedRoute` is likely wrong. When the redirect is executed, the authentication process is still going on but the user is not authenticated yet. It needs to be a public router.

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed it: I changed every URL in developer console to https:// even though I don't have it setup